# Have short comments at bottom of table in org mode (beamer/latex export)

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table

I'm trying to make a table like so:

```
|   |  x |   y |
| a | 12 | 354 |
| b | 45 |  65 |
```

Then when I export it to pdf via beamer/latex I'd like to have a short comment below it (like Souce: www.google.com). Is this possible to do?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19634/include-notes-in-table-environment-below-tabular-when-exporting-from-org-mode/19652#19652  But the answer to this question also looks nice. From my point of view non of the answers should be deleted but the topic should be merged.

Comment: @Tobias Well, this question is older than that one, so if anything that one is a duplicate of this one. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much google-ing, I've found a way to make this happen. It relies on the LaTeX package `threeparttable` so you must add that to your org preamble:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{threeparttable}
```

You can then add comments in the following manner:

```
#+begin_table
#+begin_threeparttable
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment tabular :width \textwidth :center nil
|   |  x |   y |
| a | 12 | 354 |
| b | 45 |  65 |
#+begin_tablenotes
  \item[] here are some notes \item[] Here's a note on a new line
#+end_tablenotes
#+end_threeparttable
#+end_table
```

Which produces a nicely-formatted table as a pdf through beamer.

Comment: to add a caption to the table, a `#+CAPTION: ...` line must occur directly after the `#+begin_table` line